# Where is the C++ NT2 library documentation and does it have a default popcount function?

Tags: c++

I am on the github page of the C++ library `NT2` located [in this repository](https://github.com/picanumber/nt2). When I click on the link for the developers' documentation, I get a link that goes nowhere. I am trying to read the docs to see if `NT2` offers a default popcount function.

Comment: If the link worked at some point in time, perhaps you can find a backup copy of it at Archive.org's Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested the web archive does indeed have an (incomplete) archive of the documentation:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151127024254/http://nt2.metascale.fr/doc/html/

But in your case the actual page that has the documentation for popcount isn't archived.  But the popcnt() function is defined in header nt2/bitwise/functions/popcnt.hpp which is located at

https://github.com/picanumber/nt2/blob/master/modules/boost/simd/base/include/boost/simd/bitwise/functions/popcnt.hpp

According to the header file:

```
Returns the number of bit sets the input. 

@par semantic: 
For any given value @c x of type @c T: 

@code 
as_integer<T, unsigned> r = popcnt(x); 
@endcode 

@see  @funcref{clz}, @funcref{ctz} 
@param  a0 

@return      a value of the unsigned integer 
             type associated to the input.
```

Which isn't as good as documentation would be but it does prove that popcount is in the library and does show how to call it.

I think the reason the documentation disappeared is because it seems to be in the github repository - but in quickbook form.

Comment: I am trying to get this function to work in an example:   `uint64_t x = 5;
  boost::simd::tag::as_integer<uint64_t, unsigned> r = RcppNT2::popcnt(x);` , but I get that `as_integer` is not a member of `boost::simd::tag` and it is not a member `RcppNT2`. Do you know how to call it?